# Como dar update em uma senha no MYSQL e criptografar a mesma

Tags: php, mysql

Então pessoal, quero fazer o seguinte, tenho um site que contém usuários e tal, mas na hora de um usuário querer mudar sua senha quero que a mesma vai criptografada pro BD, como posso fazer isso? na hora do usuário ser cadastrado, a senha dele vai criptografada pro MYSQL. Vou mandar o código de cadastro:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
$btnCadUsuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnCadUsuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if($btnCadUsuario){
    include_once '../Conexao/conexao.php';
    $dados_rc = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

    $erro = false;

    $dados_st = array_map('strip_tags', $dados_rc);
    $dados = array_map('trim', $dados_st);

    if(in_array('',$dados)){
        $erro = true;
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Necessário preencher todos os campos</div>";
    }elseif((strlen($dados['senha'])) < 6){
        $erro = true;
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>A senha deve ter no mínimo 6 caracteres</div>";
    }elseif(stristr($dados['senha'], "'")) {
        $erro = true;
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Caracter ( ' ) utilizado na senha é inválido</div>";
    }else{ 
        $result_usuario = "SELECT idusuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='". $dados['usuario'] ."'";
        $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
        if(($resultado_usuario) AND ($resultado_usuario->num_rows != 0)){
            $erro = true;
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Este usuário já está sendo utilizado</div>";
        }

        $result_usuario = "SELECT idusuario FROM usuarios WHERE email='". $dados['email'] ."'";
        $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
        if(($resultado_usuario) AND ($resultado_usuario->num_rows != 0)){
            $erro = true;
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Este e-mail já está sendo utilizado</div>";
        }
    }


    //var_dump($dados);
    if(!$erro){
        //var_dump($dados);
        $dados['senha'] = password_hash($dados['senha'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $result_usuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email, usuario, senha) VALUES (
                        '" .$dados['nome']. "',
                        '" .$dados['email']. "',
                        '" .$dados['usuario']. "',
                        '" .$dados['senha']. "'
                        )";
        $resultado_usario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
        if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)){
            $_SESSION['msgcad'] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!!</div>";
            header("Location: LoginPT-BR.php");
        }else{
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Error ao cadastrar usuário!!</div>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mesma logica do cadastro:

so usar sua funcao de criptografia `password_hash(string, string)` antes de enviar:

```
$dados['senha'] = password_hash($dados['senha'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Na hora de enviar, "UPDATE usuarios SET senha = md5('senha') where idusuario = '$id'"; em vez de ir isso, coloco isso "UPDATE usuarios SET senha = password_hash('senha') where idusuario = '$id'"; ?

Comment: senha = password_hash('senha', PASSWORD_DEFAULT)

Comment: Ficaria assim então: "UPDATE usuarios SET senha = password_hash('senha', PASSWORD_DEFAULT) where idusuario = '$id'";, mas mesmo assim não vai ;\  da esse error  mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in

Comment: "UPDATE usuarios SET senha = '" .password_hash('senha', PASSWORD_DEFAULT). " 'where

Comment: so faltou colocar os  ' " .

Comment: Consegui parceiro, tipo, ele está criptografando tudo certinho agora, mas quando vou tentar logar com a senha alterada não vai, sabe o pq disso?

Comment: vc conferiu a senha no banco de dados, viu como ficou?

Comment: Conferi sim amigo, ela ficou criptografada olha só, a senha que eu coloquei foi essa 9934631254a daí no banco de dados ficou assim $2y$10$2s9m6IAg2Mqb1ckZH453.uan2NuFZct4NVpeAHWdOg4lWeL67o5SG que no caso foi criptografa mas daí quando vou acessar a conta no site não loga

Comment: mas como vc confere a parte de login? vc precisa usar a mesma funcao na senha password_hash('senha', PASSWORD_DEFAULT)

Comment: Dessa forma if(password_verify($senha, $row_usuario['senha'])){

Comment: mude para isso caso sua funcao de verificacao nao converta a senha: if(password_verify(password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT), $row_usuario['senha'])){

Comment: Eu acabei de mudar, mas agora quando o usuário cria uma senha pela 1x o mesmo não consegue entrar ;\

Comment: Daí eu voltei para if(password_verify($senha, $row_usuario['senha'])){ e consegui entrar, mas quando troco a senha não dar pra entrar ueheu que brisa mano

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o md5 para inserir a senha criptografada. Um exemplo de uso seria:

- Tenho a tabela a seguir e quero atualizar a senha do usuário 1 para uma senha criptografada:
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Utilizo o comando md5('senha') para realizar, veja na prática:
  (com o comando `update tb_usuarios set dessenha = password('Kv2019@') where idusuario = 1;` também funciona, só o tipo de criptografia que muda, essa é mais uma forma de fazer hashing de senha conforme a [referência do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-hashing.html))

```
update tb_usuarios set dessenha = md5('Kv2019@') where idusuario = 1;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Agora ao selecionar o resultado a senha está salva criptografada:

```
select * from tb_usuarios;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é um exemplo utilizando a criptografia MD5. Para mais leia [este post](https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-a-criptografia-no-mysql/37179).

Obs.: Vi que você utilizou o insert, insert é para inserção/criação e update para atualizar. Utilizei o exemplo para atualizar só o campo senha, adapte ao seu código. Pois você atualiza  senha e outros campos, logos os outros campos 
também vem no update. Ex.:

```
update tb_usuarios set deslogin= 'luiz.justino', dessenha = password('Kv2019@') where idusuario = 1;
```

Que produziria:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na validação de dados você tem que passar a senha enviada pelo usuário para a forma de criptografia que usou. No nosso exemplo como utilizamos o md5, você passa senha para md5 e compara com o md5 de senha já gravado no banco de dados.

Segue uma função apenas para simples demonstração de validação de acesso:

(sempre siga [padrões da linguagem php](https://www.php-fig.org/) e [documentação do php](http://php.net/docs.php))

```
<?php



// Simulando que trazemos estas informações de um usuário que deseja acessar uma tela de login
    $id = 1;
    $login = 'luiz.justino';
    $senha = 'Kv2019@';

    $acesso = logar($login, $senha, $id);

if($acesso){
    echo "\n\n Seja bem-vindo(a) $login!";
} else {
    echo "\n\n Acesso negado!";
}

function conexaoDB(){
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'dbphp7', 3306);

if($conn->connect_error){
    echo "Error: " . $conn->connect_error;
}

return $conn;

}

function logar($login, $senha, $id){

    //Abre conexão com o banco
    $conn = conexaoDB();
    // Executa select para buscar informações do usuário de id = 1
    $sql = "select deslogin, dessenha from tb_usuarios where idusuario = $id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    // Coloco em um array as informações de deslogin e dessenha da tabela tb_usuarios do usuário de id = 1
    $resul_dados = $result->fetch_assoc();
    // Verifico se o login e senha digitados pelos usuário são iguais as informações do banco.
    // Observe que a senha digitado pelo usuário eu tenho que passar para md5 para comparar com a senha já em md5 do banco de dados
    if ($login === $resul_dados['deslogin'] && md5($senha) === $resul_dados['dessenha']){
        // Se os dados conferem a função logar retorna TRUE
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        // Se os dados NÃO conferem a função logar retorna FALSE
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

Que exibe o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vou testar aqui, mas na parte de INSERT é quando o usuário vai se cadastrar pela 1xs ó coloquei o código para demonstrar a vocês que eu tinha colocado o sistema de criptografia

Comment: Ah entendi ok. Já ia editar uma resposta com o update mas tranquilo então. Abs e sucesso cara!

Comment: então cara, usei essa sua lógica e "funcionou", tipo, a senha é criptografada e tudo, mas na hora de acessar a conta com a senha alterada não entra, tentei colocar os caracteres que vai pro banco de dados criptografado e também não funcionou, meu código foi esse "UPDATE usuarios SET senha = md5('senha') where idusuario = '$id'";

Comment: Assim que você fez o update. Se o usuário estiver logado, tem que sair e acessar novamente tenta aí.

Comment: Eu fiz isso kkk e não entra de jeito nenhum

Comment: Verifique se em sua comparação está assim: ```if (md5($senha) === $result_dados['dessenha']){
    echo "\n\n Acesso liberado!";
} else {
    echo "\n\n Acesso negado!";
} ``` . O ```md5($senha)``` é a senha que o usuário passa já o ```$result_dados['dessenha']``` é a senha que eu pego no banco de dados via select.  Pois a senha que o usuário passar você vai ter que fazer ela virar md5 para comparar com a md5 que está no banco.

Comment: @LuizFernando, ressaltando que seria interessante parametrizar a query com o método `prepare()` e `bind_param()` para evitar problemas de SQL Injection.

Comment: Eu deixei claro na minha resposta que dei um exemplo para demonstrar a função e que ele deve seguir a documentação e padrões do php . Ele seguindo a documentação e padrão vai ler sobre validação de campos e precauções de segurança.