# Como alterar senha criptografada e criptografar a mesma

Tags: php

Eaí pessoal, é o seguinte, estou com um problema no meu sistema. Eu tenho um e-commerce e nessa loja eletrônica tem a parte para os usuários se cadastrarem e até mesmo após o cadastro, alterar a senha do mesmo, enfim. Na parte de cadastro dos usuários a senha vai criptografada no BD MYSQL, até aí tudo certo, só que na hora do usuário querer alterar a senha ele consegue e a senha vai alterada para o BD, só que quando ele vai tentar entrar no sistema com a senha alterada ela não entra. Vou mostrar para vocês os códigos que usei:

**Cadastrar.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
$btnCadUsuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnCadUsuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if($btnCadUsuario){
    include_once '../Conexao/conexao.php';
    $dados_rc = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

    $erro = false;

    $dados_st = array_map('strip_tags', $dados_rc);
    $dados = array_map('trim', $dados_st);

    if(in_array('',$dados)){
        $erro = true;
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Necessário preencher todos os campos</div>";
    }elseif((strlen($dados['senha'])) < 6){
        $erro = true;
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>A senha deve ter no mínimo 6 caracteres</div>";
    }elseif(stristr($dados['senha'], "'")) {
        $erro = true;
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Caracter ( ' ) utilizado na senha é inválido</div>";
    }else{ 
        $result_usuario = "SELECT idusuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='". $dados['usuario'] ."'";
        $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
        if(($resultado_usuario) AND ($resultado_usuario->num_rows != 0)){
            $erro = true;
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Este usuário já está sendo utilizado</div>";
        }

        $result_usuario = "SELECT idusuario FROM usuarios WHERE email='". $dados['email'] ."'";
        $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
        if(($resultado_usuario) AND ($resultado_usuario->num_rows != 0)){
            $erro = true;
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Este e-mail já está sendo utilizado</div>";
        }
    }


    //var_dump($dados);
    if(!$erro){
        //var_dump($dados);
        $dados['senha'] = password_hash($dados['senha'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $result_usuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email, usuario, senha) VALUES (
                        '" .$dados['nome']. "',
                        '" .$dados['email']. "',
                        '" .$dados['usuario']. "',
                        '" .$dados['senha']. "'
                        )";
        $resultado_usario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
        if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)){
            $_SESSION['msgcad'] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!!</div>";
            header("Location: LoginPT-BR.php");
        }else{
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Error ao cadastrar usuário!!</div>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Validar.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");
$btnLogin = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnLogin', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if($btnLogin){
    $usuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $senha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    //echo "$usuario - $senha";
    if((!empty($usuario)) AND (!empty($senha))){
        //Gerar a senha criptografa
        //echo password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        //Pesquisar o usuário no BD
        $result_usuario = "SELECT idusuario, nome, email, senha FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' LIMIT 1";
        $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
        if($resultado_usuario){
            $row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);
            if(password_verify($senha, $row_usuario['senha'])){
                $_SESSION['idusuario'] = $row_usuario['idusuario'];
                $_SESSION['nome'] = $row_usuario['nome'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $row_usuario['email'];
                header("Location: ../PT-BR/PT-BR.php");
            }else{
                $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Login ou senha incorretos!</div>";
                header("Location: ../PT-BR/LoginPT-BR.php");
            }
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Preencha os dois campos abaixo!</div>";
        header("Location: ../PT-BR/LoginPT-BR.php");
    }
}else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Página não encontrada</div>";
    header("Location: ../PT-BR/LoginPT-BR.php");
}

?>
```

**Alterar_senha.php**

```
<?php
    include_once("conexao.php");
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['idusuario']);
    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);

    $result_produtos =  "UPDATE usuarios SET senha = '" .password_hash('senha', PASSWORD_DEFAULT). " 'where idusuario = '$id'";
    $resultado_produtos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_produtos);

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $result_produtos);

 // Verifica se o comando foi executado com sucesso
if (!$result)
{
    echo "Error na inserção." .mysqli_error();
    exit();
}
else
{
    $ultid =  mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    //echo $ultid;
    echo "<script>alert('Sua senha foi alterada com sucesso!!');</script>";
    //echo "<script>javascript:history.back(-4);</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location.href='../PT-BR/MinhacontaPT-BR.php?id=$id';</script>";
    //echo "header('Location: fichaanamnese.php?id=$ultid')";
}

?>
```

O problema é que quando o usuário vai tentar entrar no sistema com a senha alterada ele não consegue. Observação: quando ele altera a senha ela vai criptografada pro BD certinho.

Comment: Sua pergunta está duplicata aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/363396/como-dar-update-em-uma-senha-no-mysql-e-criptografar-a-mesma lembro que inseri um último registro lá utilizando o md5.

Comment: Não deveria ser `password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` ao invés de `password_hash('senha', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`?

Comment: vou testar Gato.

Comment: Dupliquei a pergunta pq não consegui ainda mano arrumar tentei de tudo e ngm falou mais nada

Comment: @gato eu testei dessa forma que você me disse, mas mesmo assim ele grava a senha no BD CRIPTOGRAFADA e na hora de logar ele não entra mano ;\

Comment: @PedroLukas coloquei sim cara. Lá ao usar o md5 para criptografar quando vai fazer a validação com a senha enviado pelo usuário você passa ela pra md5 pra comparar. Editei a resposta colocando exemplo completo com uso de md5, vê lá.